# UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment Discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I keep getting this error and was wondering on how to fix it:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if isinstance(message.channel, discord.channel.DMChannel) and message.author != bot.user:
         async with message.channel.typing():
             responses = ["word", "car"]
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await message.channel.send(f'{random.choice(responses)}')
```

the error I am getting is:
Ignoring exception in on_message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\endle\Documents\MyDiscordBot\bot.py", line 112, in on_message
    await message.channel.send(f'{random.choice(responses)}')
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'responses' referenced before assignment
```

Can someone help?

Comment: What would `responses` be if the `if isinstance(message.channel, discord.channel.DMChannel) . . .` check is False?

Comment: responses is a variable i use to randomly pick a string and send it

Comment: `responses` only exists as a variable when the first `if` statement is true.  If it's false, the variable is not created and you get the error.

Comment: John Gordon, Where do I make my if statement true,  Sorry I'm not the best with python

Answer (score 0):

Add an else: statement so responses is always defined.

quick example of implementing that since you said you're not super familar with python:

```py
if isinstance(message.channel, discord.channel.DMChannel) and message.author != bot.user:
    async with message.channel.typing():
        responses = ["word", "car"]
elif message.author != bot.user:
    responses = ["insert thing here"]
else:
    responses = None
```

Comment: My bot keeps replying to itself from this, if you could fix that, that would be nice. Sorry

Comment: It's giving the unbound local error again

Comment: I'm stupid, one second, you'll have to check whether responses is None or not before trying to call it, but if you do that, this should fix it

Answer (score 0):

You need an `else`. Without this, you won't actually define variable `responses` every time, so when it goes to that last line in your code, you are choosing a random element from a list that doesn't exist.

You should probably gain an understanding of elementary Python before asking questions on Stack Overflow. Some people may not be the friendliest!

[Here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py) is the discord.py documentation from Rapptz.